# Android: OnClickListener() not Working for button and image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, onclicklistener

I am new to android and this is my first app.
I am trying to navigate using button but its not working. Can someone help? 
Also, click on image is also not working.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    txt = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }


}
```

`xml` file

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_button_check_on"
    android:layout_weight="0.61"
    android:layout_marginBottom="161dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_title"
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the views that you're trying to `findViewById` in the activity's layout, or in the fragment?  If in the fragment, you should set your `onClickListener`s there.

Comment: What errors are displayed? Put the logcat file.

Comment: I am using this in activity class. Will share the log file when I am back home.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
txt = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
txt.setClickable(true);   //<----
```

and see if image onClick works.

Also while adding onClickListeners are totally fine, there is also another way of calling methods on clicking Buttons and ImageViews,

in xml add this to ImageView or Button:

```
android:onClick="launch";
```

and then you just need to create the method like,

```
public void launch(){
   //some code here
}
```

i don't know if setting onClickListeners are better than this, but i have always found this way more convenient.

Comment: It would be public void launch(View view){...}, but this should work.